# Three.js rotate boxes towards mouse position doens't work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have several randomly generated boxes that I want to rotate towards the mouse position. I tried to get the mouse position and then use `lookAt(mouse3D)`to rotate the boxes towards the mouse coordinates, but they don't change their rotation at all. I don't even want them to rotate towards the mouse position within the 3D space, simply towards the mouse position as it is on the screen.

Currently I get the mouse position like this:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
            mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3(
                 ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
                 - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
                 camera.position.z );
}
```

Here's an example I found which I wasn't able to apply to my problem: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_lookat.html

I created JSFiddle with my current approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/nrub93m7/

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/nrub93m7/4/. Its just a quick fiddle and r74 is the reason that the scene looks different.

Comment: @FalkThiele it comes really close to what I had in mind. In your example it projects the point to lookAt into the sphere along a ray, as far as I see. Is there a way to make it lookAt just the mouse position on the screen, meaning the mouses x and y coordinates but the cameras z axis coordinates?

Comment: I tried to set `var distance` to `0` but then the tiles don't turn at all anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: If this solves your problem I will clean up the code and post it as an answer: https://jsfiddle.net/nrub93m7/8/

Comment: Really close, this actually helps a lot! One thing left... have a look at this screenshot, shouldn't the tile that the arrow points at be almost flipped, because how I understand lookAt is that the flat surface should point at the vector point in 3D. http://imgur.com/tCqaYtr

Comment: @FalkThiele More like this: http://imgur.com/W7XxwlU hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yeah and you are right, its because the pivot point the tiles are looking at is projected behind the camera (http://imgur.com/LbarLYq). Like a lever to prevent the faces from making weird rotations. I didnt wanted to let this comment section go that far, sounds like you need another solution.

Comment: Can't we simply set the pivot point to where the camera is (z-wise) and then substract / add the x/y distance from the camera position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105384/discussion-between-kevin-goedecke-and-falk-thiele).

Answer (score 1):

I just added this method to your jsfiddle link:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) 
{
  mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3( event.clientX, event.clientY, 0);
}
```

Comment: this produces a weird result the objects look at some point within the sphere, but not the actual mouse position, can you have a look at the explanation I gave as a comment under the main question?

Comment: Creating a new vec every time mouse moves is expensive